# How to upgrade mysql server

Tags: linux, mysql

How can i upgrade mysql version 5.0.22 to version 5.0.51a ??

My server info:

Linux version 2.6.18-8.1.8.el5 (gcc version 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)

Thanks

Comment: Make sure to associate your accounts on the accounts tab on your user page.

Answer (score 2):

obviously:

```
yum upgrade mysql*
```

but, please, don't forget that:

```
mysqldump
```

is your best friend!!!

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the basic (correct) answer that pulegium gave...

You are using either RHEL5 or CentOS5; enable your yum system with the IUS Community repository, it's a shared repo (like EPEL) that aims to provide newer PHP and MySQL packages that fit right into your server that was started by Rackspace employees.

Start here: http://wiki.iuscommunity.org/Doc/ClientUsageGuide

While 5.0.51a is the latest Red Hat provides, IUS is providing 5.0.88 as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

yum upgrade mysql*

Answer (score 1):

Instructions on handling mysql upgrades, regarding the db itself, are in [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installing.html). When you change minor version (eg. form 5.0.x to 5.0.y) there usually isn't very much to do (if anything at all) - although there can always be some minor tweaks here and there.

Instructions about upgrading a package on your distro are in the documentation of your distro.

All in all, I do recommend you to follow the usual updates that come with your distribution of choice. If they bundle some version of MySQL, stick with that unless you have a very good reason not to do so. For a db server, I'd upgrade the whole system rather than putting an 'external' package in the distro - but that's me.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum update mysql-5.0.51a` perhaps.

Of course checking that mysql-5.0.51a is indeed the correct name in the yum repositotry for MySQL.